# varnish: how to split log files based on vhosts

Tags: varnish

I'm using varnish 4. I want to see the web traffic for awstats, but all the samples I found on the Internet look like `varnishncsa -m "RxHeader:^Host: domain.com$" -a -w blabla`. The problem is that the latest version of varnishncsa doesn't know about the "m" option

```
$ varnishncsa -V
varnishncsa (varnish-4.0.3 revision b8c4a34)
Copyright (c) 2006 Verdens Gang AS
Copyright (c) 2006-2014 Varnish Software AS
$ varnishncsa -m "RxHeader:^Host: domain.com$" -a -w /web/htdocs/olivier/stats/awstats-7.4/test.tmp
varnishncsa: invalid option -- 'm'
```

Thus how should I do to split log files based on my vhosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the "`-q`" option.

Here's a working sample:

```
varnishncsa -a -D \
    -q 'ReqHeader:Host ~ "mywebsite"' \
    -w /web/logs/mywebsite/access.varnish.log \
    -P /var/run/varnishncsa.mywebsite.pid
```